# How to pass in variable length variable to statement.Exec?

Tags: go

For example

```
func Query(myvarlist []string) {
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
        myvar = $1 AND myvar2 = $2".......)

    defer stmt.Close()

    if _, err := stmt.Exec(myvarlist....); err != nil {
    
}
```

Can we pass in `Exec` a variable length variable?

Comment: Could you show all the code? I want to know how to connect the database and which database and package you used.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question but I think that you could pass is as first param no? Like `stmt Exec(len(myvarlist), myvarlist...)`. But you will need to change you query

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the this:

```golang
func Query() {
    db, err := sql.Open("pgx", `postgresql://CONNSTRING`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    queryParamMap := map[string]string{
        "id":   "6",
        "name": "1",
    }

    // Build up statement and params
    cols := make([]string, len(queryParamMap))
    args := make([]any, len(queryParamMap))
    i := 0
    for k, v := range queryParamMap {
        cols[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%s = $%d", k, i+1) // WARNING - SQL Injection possible here if col names are not sanitised
        args[i] = v
        i++
    }
    // Using Prepare because the question used it but this is only worthwhile if you will run stmt multiple times
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`SELECT id FROM devices WHERE ` + strings.Join(cols, " and "))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    rows, err := stmt.Query(args...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        if err = rows.Scan(&id); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("value:", id)
    }
    // Should check rows.Error() etc but this is just an example...
}
```

I've put the column names and values into a map because it was not clear where any extra column names would come from in your question but hopefully this provides the info you need.

This example is also using `Query` rather than `Exec` (because it's easier to test) but the same approach will work with `Exec`.

Note: Take a look at [squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel) for an example of how to take this a lot further....