# Create dynamic query for postgresql in golang with map[string]interface{} input

Tags: string, postgresql, go

I have map[string]interface input **user** like below

```
user := map[string]interface{}{
       "firstname": firstname,
       "lastname":  lastname,
       "country":   country,
       "email":     email,
   }
```

> Values given above are from other functions as variables hence not indicated in "".

For example, I need to generate a dynamic query as follows from the above interface: `"INSERT INTO USERTABLE (key1, key2, key3, key4) VALUES (val1, val2, val3, val4) RETURNING id`

where the iterator will count keys and values and will generate the query as below

`"INSERT INTO USERTABLE (firstname, lastname, country, email) VALUES (firstname, lastname, country, email) RETURNING userid"`

Looking to build a dynamic string.

Comment: What have you tried? show us your code, your attempt. What problems did you encounter? show the exact error message or describe in precise terms the specific algorithm you want to, but weren't able to, implement. Also see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73849016/11810946) a similar question yesterday - the same technique will probably work for you.

Comment: Voting to close because your edit significantly changes the required output and you have not indicated what specific problem you are facing, or added any code showing your attempt at this. Be very careful when creating dynamic SQL; if the values (e.g. `firstname`) are user provided then you are opening yourself up to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection); your initial approach is probably better than the edited one (but as you have not provided any info on your end goal its difficult to say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure Go

```
func prepareInsert(table string, params map[string]interface{}) string {
    columns := len(params)
    fieldSlice := make([]string, 0, columns)
    for field, _ := range params {
        fieldSlice = append(fieldSlice, field)
    }
    fields := strings.Join(fieldSlice, ",")

    placeholders := prepareQueryPlaceholders(1, columns)
    return fmt.Sprintf(`INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s) RETURNING %s`, table, fields, placeholders, fields)
}

func prepareQueryPlaceholders(start, quantity int) string {
    placeholders := make([]string, 0, quantity)
    end := start + quantity
    for i := start; i < end; i++ {
        placeholders = append(placeholders, strings.Join([]string{"$", strconv.Itoa(i)}, ""))
    }
    return strings.Join(placeholders, ",")
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/_cw7l2S6WJx)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for you time, your code outputs INSERT INTO USERTABLE (firstname,lastname,country,email) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING firstname,lastname,country,email, whereas we need ("INSERT INTO USERTABLE (firstname, lastname, country, email) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING userid", firstname, lastname, country, email).

I made updates to your code to match my requirements but the SQL throws errors for invalid syntax. Apparently this doesn't work

Comment: if you try to execute  `"INSERT INTO USERTABLE (firstname, lastname, country, email) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING userid" , firstname, lastname, country, email`   the error is expectable -> because syntax is really invalid.

Comment: Yes, realised that, I have made changes to my original question